# Can Cloudflare or Nginx strip the body of an inbound request?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I'm trying to create a basic api which does stuff, as an api does, however it is sitting behind both an Nginx instance and a Cloudflare layer for security, however every time I make a request all the headers go through find but the body of the request (application/json) seems to be getting removed.

I have tried logging it on the nginx instance and I just get '-' every request so I think it could be Cloudflare. I have tested locally and I am definitely able to receive the body as it is. I've looked through the req object and there is no body anywhere, all the auth headers are fine just the body.

[image: Blank Body in NGINX log]

[image: NGINX config]

EDIT (in response to AD7six): Sorry i'll clear my question up, i'm saying that both the access log is missing the body and that my code behind the proxy does not receive it. I'll attach the nginx config / log now.

On further inspection my nginx config is listening to port 80 however all the responses are going to https... I hope that makes sense.

NGINX Config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        log_format postdata $request_body;

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;
                server_name dev.ru-pirie.com;

                location / {
                        access_log  /var/log/nginx/postdata.log  postdata;

                        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.74:3000;
                }
        }
}
```

All the log contains is `-` per request

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Are you saying _the access log_ is missing the body, or that the proxied service does not receive the body? In either case **please edit the question to provide some relevant nginx access logs** (and applicable nginx config as text). A common cause is a request being redirected (e.g. http -> https) and thus having no body as it’s a get request.

Comment: Sorry i'll clear my question up, i'm saying that both the access log is missing the body and that my code behind the proxy does not receive it. I'll attach the nginx config / log now.

Comment: The log message from  `/var/log/nginx/access.log` is what would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

When requests are proxied via Cloudflare, by default they are modified with additional headers, for example `CF-Connecting-IP` that shows the IP of the original client that has sent the request ([full list here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/http-request-headers/)).

There are other features that Cloudflare users can implement that may alter the request, but only when explicitly configured to do so: for example, someone could write a [Cloudflare Worker](https://workers.cloudflare.com/) that modifies arbitrarily the incoming request before forwarding it to the origin server. Other general HTTP request changes are possible using [Cloudflare Rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/).

Cloudflare would not alter the body of an incoming request before passing it to the origin, unless explicitly configured to do so for example with Workers.